# How can I convert the values in my row to column values in an Excel file? If you have any suggestions or solutions, please

Tags: excel

For example I have Employees monthly shifts roster values like below.[Rows Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQFNx.png)

I want to convert it to column wise for each employees as per below. [To Columns]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTuz3.png)
If you have any suggestions or solutions, please ....

Comment: Unpivot --> Research More!

Comment: can you paste your code instead of giving a picture?

Comment: Rows data
EmployeeID Name   1/2 2/2 3/2 4/2 5/2 6/2 7/2 8/2 9/2 10/2
EMP01  Employee Name1 M M M M M M - M M M 
EMP02  Employee Name2 E E E E E E - E E E 
EMP03  Employee Name3 N N N N N N - N N N 


To columns
EmployeeID Name   Date Shift
EMP01  Employee Name1 1/2  M
EMP01     Employee Name1 2/2     M
EMP01     Employee Name1 3/2     M
EMP01     Employee Name1 4/2     M
EMP01     Employee Name1 5/2     M
EMP01     Employee Name1 6/2     M
EMP01     Employee Name1 7/2     -
EMP01     Employee Name1 8/2     M
EMP01     Employee Name1 9/2     M